# Same time, two client send answer to server nodejs express (use socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I writting server game use nodejs and socket.io 
In this game, I have two client (player), two player will join to room and server will send 1 question with 4 answers. When the first player send correct answer to server, the second player cann't send answer to client (or server not accept answer). 
**I have issues**: 
1. How to server know this question, the first player correct answer and not accept answer from second player? 
2. If same time, when server check answer of first player, the second player send answer. How to server check who win if two player correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I have an assumption to this problem. According to my point of view, when server starts listening for client connections...

1. limit the number of clients to two.
2. once connections got established with both the clients, send the  question  in the buffer to both the clients and set a flag = 0
3. after the question is sent enter into a loop to get back a reply from any of the client side.
4. On successful acceptance of an answer check for its correctness, if its matches, set the flag = 1, and break the loop which will stop accepting answers from the client side.

Using this flag in this loop can help the server to know not to accept anymore answers.

For your second question, I would say, if both of them answer at a same time i.e. second client answers even before checking of the correctness of the answer of first client, can result in draw. Though I don't have any clear assumption in this situation.